# how do I filter tags with django-tagging?

Tags: django, django-tagging

I'm using the django app django-tagging and I'm trying to filter out certain tags for a simple tag search.

the variable 'tag' is text of some tag I am searching for.
'Widget' is the model associated with the tags.

```
tags = Tag.objects.usage_for_model(Widget, counts=True, filters=dict(tags__icontains=tag))
```

The code above sort of works.  It returns a list of tags which contain the tag, but it also returns other tags associated with widgets that use that tag.

For example, I have a widget: A, and A has tags: django, python, mysql.
If I do a simple search for 'django':

```
tags = Tag.objects.usage_for_model(Widget, counts=True, filters=dict(tags__icontains='django'))
```

tags will return this list: [(Tag: django), (Tag: python), (Tag: mysql)]

I only want it to return: [(Tag: django)]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never?

```
djangoTag = Tag.objects.get(name='django')
djangoWidgets = TaggedItem.objects.get_union_by_model(Widget, djangoTag)
```